# Bring image on top of view in react native, zIndex doesn't work

Tags: react-native, elevation

I am developing an application using react native. i have a dashboard page which include two view, inside each one image and another view
i have added elevation to the sub view but then the image set in the back which the view covering it and i want to make the image in front of the view.
May this sound a bit complicated to understand but here is the code for what I'm trying to explain

```
      <View style={styles.sectionStyle}>
            <View>
                <Image style={styles.actionimg} source={require('../assest/img/admin7.png')} />
                <View style={styles.rectangle} />
            </View>
            <View>
              
                <Image style={styles.actionimg} source={require('../assest/img/admin8.png')} />
                <View style={styles.rectangle1} />
            </View>
     </View>
```

so the problem I figured it out which the elevation property that set to `<View>`  refer to `style={styles.rectangle}`

so when I remove the elevation the image it appeared in the top.

here how it look with elevation:
[image: with elevation]

and here without elevation:
[image: without elevation]

I tried to set the image inside another view and style it with elevation property but that doesn't work, also tried `zIndex` with `absolute` but it doesn't work
I hope someone can help me how to figure that.

here is the styling:

```
rectangle1: {

    width: 150,
    height: 200,
    borderRadius: 13,
    backgroundColor: "#ffffff",
    margin: 10,
    elevation: 5
  },
  rectangle: {

    width: 150,
    height: 200,
    borderRadius: 13,
    backgroundColor: "#6dacbc",
    margin: 10,
    elevation: 5,

  },
 actionimg: {
    position: 'absolute',
    zIndex: 8000
  }, 
sectionStyle: {
    flex: 1,
    alignItems: 'center',
    flexDirection: 'row',
    height: 40,
    width: 300,
    borderRadius: 5,
    margin: 50,
    top: -40,
    left: -20,

  },
```

Answer (score 0):

You can give zIndex to container rectangle if Platform is Ios. If platform is Android, you must give `elevation`lover than Image view's elevation

```json
rectangle1: {
  width: 150,
  height: 200,
  borderRadius: 13,
  backgroundColor: '#ffffff',
  margin: 10,
  elevation: 5,
  zIndex: 1
},
rectangle: {
  width: 150,
  height: 200,
  borderRadius: 13,
  backgroundColor: '#6dacbc',
  margin: 10,
  elevation: 5,
  zIndex: 1
}
```

Comment: giving elevation lower for rectangle it works